# PHP Symfony FOSRestBundle and Dependency Injection

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, fosrestbundle

Assumed I have a normal Symfony entity "Car", a self written service "Log" and I want to build a rest route

```
    PUT http://mysite.de/api/{version}/cars/{oldcar}
```

to do something with a car given in "oldcar" stored in my database. In the body of the PUT there comes another Car object in JSON notation with the new data. Then I have following method:

```
    /**
     * @Rest\Put("/api/{version}/cars/{oldcar}")
     * @ParamConverter("oldcar", class="MyBundle\Entity\Car")
     * @ParamConverter("newcar", class="MyBundle\Entity\\Car", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     */
    public function putAction(Log $logger, EntityManagerInterface $em, Car $oldcar, Car $newcar)
    {
            ... update the oldcar in the database with data from the newcar ...
    }
```

**I got this allready working!**

But now I want to know: Is there a configuration of the FosRestBundle to omit the @ParamConverter annotations? In my opinion there are enough information for the framework to do this automatically without them.

Log and EntityManagerInterface can be found in the service container. oldcar's and newcar's types are defined in the method signature. Primary key for database access for oldcar is given by the route. There is only the JSON data in the body left for newcar.

**Does anybody here get this working without the @ParamConverter annotations?**

Please tell me if and a short idear how.

Comment: Why you don't like to use ParamConverter ?
Without ParamConverter, you should get old car manually : request data from DB with id given by route.

Comment: Because I dont know why...that oldcar is an Car you can see in the signature, Why do i have to annotate this? However, I want to know if there is a way to do it without @ParamConverter. At least the first one, better both.

Comment: I'm sure sensioframeworkextrabundle do the job for oldcar, the container DI shouldn't be a problem, so only the body data newcar has to be deserialized automatically by the rest bundle. I believe there is a configuration that do the job.

Comment: If you use type hinting like for your exemple Car $oldcar, you can even omit the @ParamConverter annotation altogether see doc usage:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#usage

Comment: To do this I have to enable auto_convert of the sensioframeworkextrabundle. But then I get exceptions like: ```The provided type \"Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityManagerInterface\" is an interface, and can not be instantiated```. The DI of the container does not work then, don't know why. Why corrupts auto_convert the container-DI?

Comment: it is enabled by default look at doc don't need to configure it:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#configuration